# Exporting reflowable Content from InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, digital-printing

I know I can create interactive and fluid alternate layouts in InDesign but can I export that as a single document using InDesign's online publisher and still be able to resize the browser to show different screen sizes like you can do with any responsive website or export from Muse?

Every example I see online of "Online Publisher", people only show the interactivity but don't' show the content responding as the browser gets resized. Is it even something it can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how much interactive/fluidity you are looking for in your final document.  I don't have much need to create interactive PDFs, so my experience is limited to standard PDFs.  And, in general, I get pretty frustrated with Adobe's Publish Online feature, because it is quite limited (really?  The only way to rename a file is to actually re-upload it with a new name and delete the version that had the old name?).

That said, it does seem to be responsive to screen size.  Here's an example of one of my documents with my browser taking up my entire screen:
[image]

And here it is with the browser window resized to about 1/3 of my screen size:

[image]

And finally, here is a screenshot from my puny iPhone 5 screen: 
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I was kind of hoping for a responsive layout that could go from something like four columns on a desktop to two columns on a tablet and one column on a mobile.  Is this something ePub could do?

Comment: I don't know very much at all about ePubs, but I don't believe something like this is within the capability of an ePub.  I think the type of change you describe requires more HTML than you get with an ePub.  I think you would need something like Adobe Muse to create a website that appeared to be a book.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help and I will start looking into Muse, Thank you.